# Eclipse forces me to add library's dependency as a project

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, build-system

I develop for Android using eclipse and my project depends on several external libraries, some of them I add as a jar, others I add as sub projects. Some projects accesses internal resources from others, which obliges me importing the dependency as a sub

Now, I'm going to add another library (PullToRefresh) as a dependency, which depends on a second library. PullToRefresh uses gradle, which resolves dependencies smoothly, but I should add it to Eclipse, in order to develop my application.

The problem is Eclipse isn't aware of gradle dependency management, so when I import PullToRefresh into eclipse, it gives me compilation errors. So this situation obliges me to import PullToRefresh dependency to eclipse in order to compile everything.

I understand that I can see Eclipse and Gradle as two separate building systems, but I'd like to find a better solution to the problem, one that doesn't force me to add my libraries' dependencies into Eclipse. Any ideias?

I have to say that my application and dependencies successfully compile using Gradle, without manually downloading PullToRefresh dependency.

Comment: reverting gradle build structure to ant is as easy as moving folders around.

Comment: @user1281750 I see, but how moving to ant can help me?

Comment: It is not a choice, when using eclipse your are bound using ant. See this link how to set up dependecies and such http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html